# 'External: SIGSEGV' при считывании строк из файла в динамический массив

Tags: pascal, lazarus, delphi

Здравствуйте.

Возникает ошибка процессора, когда считываю из файла строки в динамический массив. IDE Lazarus v.1.2.4, Free Pascal. Не доходит в чём причина ошибки.

Код должен из входного файла "ip.in" считать:

```
 3
 194.85.160.177
 194.85.160.183
 194.85.160.178
```

и вывести результат работы программы в "ip.out".

Вот код:

```
 program ipnetworks;        
 var m, i: integer;
     ip: array of string;

 begin
     assign(input, 'ip.in');
     assign(output, 'ip.out');
     reset(input);
     rewrite(output);

     readln(m);
     setlength(ip, m);

     for i := 1 to m do
        begin
            readln(ip[i]);
            writeln(ip[i]);
        end;
     close(input);
     close(output);
 end.
```

В результате возникает ошибка:
"Проект ipnetworks вызвал класс исключения 'External: SIGSEGV'. По адресу 4023A1".

Программа работает, если запустить то же самое, но с пустым циклом:

```
program ipnetworks;

var m, i: integer;
ip: array of string;

begin
  assign(input, 'ip.in');
  assign(output, 'ip.out');
  reset(input);
  rewrite(output);

  readln(m);
  setlength(ip, m);

  for i := 1 to m do
  begin
      //readln(ip[i]);
      //writeln(ip[i]);
  end;
  close(input);
  close(output);
end.
```

или, если установить сразу размер массива:

```
program ipnetworks;

var m, i: integer;
ip: array [1..3] of string; //задаём размер при объявлении, тогда считывает норм

begin
  assign(input, 'ip.in');
  assign(output, 'ip.out');
  reset(input);
  rewrite(output);

  readln(m);
  //setlength(ip, m);

  for i := 1 to m do
  begin
      readln(ip[i]);
      writeln(ip[i]);
  end;
  close(input);
  close(output);
end.
```

В чём ошибка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Документация](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/setlength.html) гласит:

> In the case of a dynamical array *A*, `setlength` sets the number of elements. The elements are numbered from index 0, so the count runs from 0 to `Len-1`.

Попробуйте

```
for i := 0 to m - 1 do
```

(А вообще, если честно, вашему коду в его нынешнем состоянии вовсе не нужен массив. Достаточно завести `string`, в котором будет помещаться текущая строка. Но вам, возможно, считанный массив понадобится в будущем.)

Comment: Спасибо большое, VladD :)

Да, думаю, что массив нужен. Программа должна найти наименьшую из возможных сеть, в которую бы входили все представленные во входном файле IP адреса. Всего адресов в файле может быть от 1 до 1000 включительно.

Comment: @Art Mart: Угу, я так и понял, что это упрощённый пример (и это правильно).